# SOAP API v42: Edit "Default Organization Level Values" of Custom Settings

Tags: soap, java

How to edit Default Organization Level Values of Custom Settings in Soap API in Java?

I mean, how to edit...

`Setup > Build > Develop > Custom Settings > [Any CS Object] > Manage > Edit > [fields listed here]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Org-level Default Custom Settings are created, inserted, and queried just like any other sObject.

The key differentiator is the value populated in the `SetupOwnerId` field, which defines whether the Custom Setting record is associated to a user (the user's Id), a profile (the profile's Id), or the entire organization (the org's Id).

You can obtain the org Id from the [`getUserInfo()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_getuserinfo.htm) SOAP call.